# tinyMce activeeditor is null on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce

I am using `tinymce editor` to a textarea with exact id. It is working fine on pageload.
But when I am clicking asp button 'Save'  whick post backs to save the data in DB the active editor becomes null and does not retains its value.
How to overcome this problem?

My tinyMce init code in pageload is

```
tinyMCE.init({
mode: "exact",
elements : "divLabTemplateTree",
encoding: "xml",
convert_urls: false,
theme: "advanced",
width:"300",
height:"400",
skin : "o2k7",
plugins: "spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,paste,directionality,fullscreen,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
extended_valid_elements: "iframe[src|width|height|name|align]",
theme_advanced_buttons1: "spellchecker,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,print,fullscreen",
theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,media,advhr,|",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
theme_advanced_path_location: "bottom",
theme_advanced_resizing: true,
theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,    
dom_loaded : 1,
theme_advanced_styles: "Link to Image: lightbox;Image Right Border: rightbordered;Image Left Border: leftbordered;Darker Text: darker",
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.onSaveContent.add(function (i, o) {
        o.content = o.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
    });

    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "divLabTemplateTree");
    });

    }
});
```

I am setting its value

```
if(tinyMCE.activeEditor != null)
{
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a page gets initialized tinyMCE.activeEditor is null till the moment when a user explicitly clicks into the editor.

It is recommended to use `tinymce.get('your_editor_id')` here. Your editor is equals your textarea id for which the editor gets initialized. If this textarea (or other html source elmenent) got no id then `content` is used as default.

Comment: `tinymce.get('your_editor_id').setContent(Text)` is not assigning the text to the editor on postback.

Comment: you need to insert your own id. Btw. are you using tinymce4?

Comment: I am using my id only here I have written just for the syntax. I am using `tinymce3.7`

Comment: @Thariama I'm having the same problem as OP but your solution returns `null` for me (on tinyMCE 4.1.5)

Comment: Juicy: Keep in mind that tinymce.get('your_editor_id') will only work after the editor got initialized (you may use the oninit Handler here to do things after initialization) and of course you will need to insert your own editor id here and not "your_editor_id".

Comment: How do we know what to put for `'your_editor_id'`?

Comment: @David: to get your editors id eighter use tinymce.activeEditor.id or use the attribute id of the textarea tag that the editor has been initialized for